# Prevent resume from suspend on lid open for 14.04

Tags: 14.04, power-management, suspend, asus

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on an Asus n550jv. I had this problem in 13.10 also.

I want to disable resume-from-suspend when the laptop lid is opened. The traditional answers to this involve `echo "LID" > /proc/acpi/wakeup`, but there is no entry for LID in this file:

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
RP01      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:04:00.0
WLAN      S3    *disabled
RP04      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:05:00.0
GLAN      S4    *disabled
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
XHC   S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
PEG0      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.0
PEGP      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:01:00.0
PEGA      S4    *disabled
PEG1      S4    *disabled
PEG2      S4    *disabled
SLPB      S4    *enabled
```

acpi_listen isn't very helpful either:

```
$ acpi_listen 
button/lid LID 00000080 000000f5
video GFX0 00000080 00000000
button/lid LID 00000080 000000f6
video GFX0 00000080 00000000
```

I found some additional info, but sadly this does not help:

Toggle /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/lid_resume using

```
# echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/lid_resume
```

Refs:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/c0b91b6d5226247fa4fe894eb592bcc56bc7e9fd
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/S3

Comment: I actually want to enable resume when LID is opened :) But I also do not have LID listed in wakeup (sorry have to move to answer as this doesn't allow long paste)